# How use global static const string?

Tags: string, rust, global

There is a `ALPHABET` for arithmetic, it's const and used in a lot of functions. I want make the `ALPHABET` global, static, and const. Some functions need the `ALPHABET` type as `&String`, but `str.to_string()` function will happen once memory copy. this function is called frequently, so it's not good.

The used function is a library, can't change it.

```rust
static ALPHABET: &str = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

fn some1(value: &String, alphabet: &String) -> String {
    xxxx
}

fn main() {
    some1("test", ALPHABET); // Can't build
    some1("test", &ALPHABET.to_string()); // OK, but will happend memory copy.
}
```

How use the `ALPHABET` without `to_string()` function?

Comment: See also why [it is discouraged for functions to accept `&String` or `&Vec<_>` parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219). A well designed function would not require that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if your function uses `&str` instead:

```rust
fn some1(value: &str, alphabet: &str) -> String {
    xxxx
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66ea5f9099fe84d636e2dbc91dbf703b)

Since this is in a library you cannot modify, you could use [`lazy_static`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.4.0/lazy_static/) to instantiate a static reference to the `String`:

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static; // 1.4.0

lazy_static! {
    static ref APLHABET: String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".to_string();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=393ce8ec1341927f6b7a21e54a1ebb82)

Comment: I know, but the function is a library, can't change it.